# Django User Registration - Password Reset via email

Tags: django

As title explains.

Is there a built in method within Django 1.5 that handles user password resets?
i.e. Via an email reset link?

Need my users to have a "Forgot Password" link.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes there is.

You can use this form too in your **forms.py**

```
class PassworResetForm(forms.Form):
    error_messages = {
        'unknown': ("That email address doesn't have an associated "
                     "user account. Are you sure you've registered?"),
        'unusable': ("The user account associated with this email "
                      "address cannot reset the password."),
        }
    def clean_email(self):
        """
        Validates that an active user exists with the given email address.
        """
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        self.users_cache = UserModel._default_manager.filter(email__iexact=email)
        if not len(self.users_cache):
            raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['unknown'])
        if not any(user.is_active for user in self.users_cache):
            # none of the filtered users are active
            raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['unknown'])
        if any((user.password == UNUSABLE_PASSWORD)
            for user in self.users_cache):
            raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['unusable'])
        return email

    def save(self, domain_override=None,
             subject_template_name='registration/password_reset_subject.txt',
             email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html',
             use_https=False, token_generator=default_token_generator,
             from_email=None, request=None):
        """
        Generates a one-use only link for resetting password and sends to the
        user.
        """
        from django.core.mail import send_mail
        for user in self.users_cache:
            if not domain_override:
                current_site = get_current_site(request)
                site_name = current_site.name
                domain = current_site.domain
            else:
                site_name = domain = domain_override
            c = {
                'email': user.email,
                'domain': domain,
                'site_name': site_name,
                'uid': int_to_base36(user.pk),
                'user': user,
                'token': token_generator.make_token(user),
                'protocol': use_https and 'https' or 'http',
                }
            subject = loader.render_to_string(subject_template_name, c)
            # Email subject *must not* contain newlines
            subject = ''.join(subject.splitlines())
            email = loader.render_to_string(email_template_name, c)
            send_mail(subject, email, from_email, [user.email])
```

You must generate the html template for send to the user:

```
{% autoescape off %}
    You're receiving this e-mail because you requested a password reset for your user account at {{ site_name }}.

    Please go to the following page and choose a new password:
    {% block reset_link %}
       {{ domain }}{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' uidb36=uid token=token %}
    {% endblock %}

    Your username, in case you've forgotten: {{ user.username }}

    Thanks for using our site!

    The {{ site_name }} team.

{% endautoescape %}
```

And add this url to the **urls.py**

```
(r'^accounts/password/reset/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset',
     {'post_reset_redirect' : '/accounts/password/reset/done/'}),
    (r'^accounts/password/reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done'),
    (r'^accounts/password/reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm',
     {'post_reset_redirect' : '/accounts/password/done/'}),
    (r'^accounts/password/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete'),
```

Make a template for each url

Comment: One suggestion: removing the error messages might be a good idea.  If you just say "email sent", you don't leak information about who is registered in your system.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the default django-admin urls

Add `url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),`
to your urls.py

Add email credentials to the settings.py

```
# using gmail as my smtp server
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'example@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Then use the link http://baseurl/password_reset/